# How can I create a dot filled line in ToC of KOMA-Script on part level?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

What I want to achieve is a dotted line in the table of contents of a `scrbook` document. However I only found an opion to do this on chapter level `toc=chapterentrydotfill`, the logical `toc=partentrydotfill` does not exist and hence my MWE:

```
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrydotfill,toc=partentrydotfill]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{foo1}
\chapter{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{part}
```

or

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{part}
```

Both can be used for chapters too.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{part,chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{foo1}
\chapter{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\end{document}
```

[image]